# Backwards compatible LinearLayout constructor

Tags: java, android, android-linearlayout, backwards-compatibility, super

I'm writing an Android app that needs to run on Android 2.3.3 (yeay fragmentation!). Since that version, `LinearLayout` has introduced an additional constructor, so I want to be able to do something like this:

```
public class ActionMenuTextItemView extends LinearLayout
{
    public ActionMenuTextItemView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
    {
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11)
            super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        else
            super(context, attrs);
    }
```

It doesn't work because `super` has to be the first line. Is there a way around this (other than building two versions of the APK)? Obviously I will probably end up just using the two-parameter version all the time, but I want to know if there is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

You can have two constuctors like below. Use one in Gingerbread and the other one in Honeycomb and above.

```
public class ActionMenuTextItemView extends LinearLayout
{
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    public ActionMenuTextItemView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public ActionMenuTextItemView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
    }
}
```